# Use of the definite article in a date

Tags: definite-articles, dates

Where is it appropriate to insert the definite article in a date? For example, how would I say that something will be delivered on Thursday, the 9th of July?

For example, are the following sentences idiomatic? I have placed the words I am unsure about in uppercase.

> 1. Something will be delivered THE Thursday THE 09/07
> 2. We will complete this task THE Monday THE 01/08.

Comment: It depends on the context.  Can you provide more context?

Comment: Hi Phoog. For example I have to say two sentences:1) something will be delivered THE tursday THE 09/07. 2) we will complete this task THE monday THE 01/08. In uppercase my doubts

Comment: Edit your question, don't add the information in a comment.

Comment: Are you asking about spoken or written English? If you are asking about written, **all** of your THEs should be left out. Not only are they not _necessary_, they are not _allowable_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, when referring to a date without a year, there are two common approaches

> July 12th
>
> and
>
> *the* 12th of July

In general, when referring to a weekday without further modifier, *the* is not used

> I will see you on Monday.
>
> and
>
> I need that report by Monday.

However, when you are referring to a particular day of the week, but indicating which one of the many possible instances of that day by adding a modifying phrase, *the* often (but not always) precedes the day

> I will see you on the Monday after next.
>
> and
>
> I will see you on the first Monday of every month.

When you combine a reference to a date with a reference to the weekday that date falls on, the weekday is not usually further defined, so

> I will see you on Monday, July 12th.
>
> and
>
> I Will see you on Monday, the 12th of July.

Answer (score 1):

The first "the" in both sentences is unnecessary. You could use "by" instead of them.

Answer (score 1):

Spoken aloud, those should be:

> Something will be delivered *on* Thursday, *the* 7th of August.
>
> We will complete this task *on* Monday, *the* 8th of January.

To say that the events are expected to happen at some point during those days and at no other time.

In writing, you could contract that to:

> Something will be delivered *on* Thursday, 09/07.
>
> We will complete the task *on* Monday, 01/08.

In both cases, you may choose to say 'by' instead of 'on', which would instead indicate that the task may be finished sooner, but will in any case delivered no later than the indicated date.